# How to calculate time of passing the discrete path of cells?

Tags: algorithm, lua

Let's say we have a field of descrete cells (2d array or table). We have some finite path inside of it with no self-crossings and no diagonal connections. The particle starts its way in the point A and follows the pattern to the point B. One step can be done in the finite amount of time = t. So the time for the whole path will be T = t * l, where l = number of cells in the path. But! We have some cells in the field marked as 'h' and 'v'. If the particle hit the 'h' cell then it divides into 3 particles. One continue moving by the path. Second starts to move left from the 'h' cell to the left border of the field. Third starts to move right from the 'h' cell to the right border of the field. Analogically with the 'v' cell, but instead of left/right, another 2 particles start move up/down. All particles are moving simultaneously with the same speed. Additional particles can collect 'h' and 'v' too and also can be divided and spawn more particles. Need to write function in Lua that calculates time from the moment of first particle starts its way to the moment of all particles finished their ways. See related illustation. Note that once 'h' or 'v' cell have been collected it becomes a simple cell and other particles doesn't divide if hitting it.
[image: Example 1]

Comment: Any solution in pseudocode will be appreciated too.

Answer (score 0):

There's not much of an algorithm that can be done here apart from the direct running of the simulations.
There can be no apriori knowledge of the simulation time since the movement of different particles alters the conditions for other particle movement (as in during harvest act).

If the `v` and `h` tiles remained after the interaction process then you could just perform a simple raytracing i.e. scan the route, find `v` and `h` tiles scan the lines drawn from `v` and`h` tiles, find `v`,`h` or border tiles, calculate the longest path, draw lines from newfound `v`,`h` and scan those, and so on until all lines hit the border or lock into loop. To ignore looped results you could memorize which tiles have been already visited by currently examined ray and its predecessors.

Obviously, as special tiles (`v`,`h`) can only prolong the simulation time, the result from above would give upper limit of time in simulation with disappearing special tiles. To calculate the exact runtime, you'd need to take into account the moment in time at which a particular tile is triggered. Surely, it is possible to do that with rays, but a little of thought is needed that it'd be an equivalent to a direct simulation of particles.

The code for that is pretty simple and I will only briefly outline algorithm:

```
%make array for particlesenter code here
particles={}

%define initial particle route
route={{x1,y1},{x2,y2},...}

%probably you should have your field defined somewhere here too
v_tiles={{x1,y1},{x2,y2}...}
h_tiles=...

%make particle, possible implementations are numerous really
%for example it could be represented by its position 
%and a function which gives next position, based on current one
%for main particle it could search the route table for a current position and return next element, 
%or just use external counter variable to keep track of propagation
particle={position={x,y}, propagator=function({x,y}) ....}

%put that into particles array obviously

%initialize counter
T=0
%run a cycle until there are particles
while #particles>0 do

    %perform a single step for all the particles
    for _,p in pairs(particles) do
        %move them all
        p.position=p.propagator(p.position)
    endfor
    %then check them all
    for i,p in pairs(particles) do
        %check for special tiles 
        if is_v(p.position) then
            %make new particle
            table.insert(particles,{
                position={p.position.x, p.position.y+1},
                %for secondary particles propagator would be just a constant addition to a single coordinate
                propagator=function(pos) return {pos.x,pos.y+1} end
                })
            %make second new particle

        %same for h tiles
        if is_h(p.position) then ...

        %check for border tile
        if is_border(p.position) then
            %remove those that are at the border
            table.remove...
            %for the original particle you'd have to check 
            %whether it has reached destination
            %probably you should check that somewhere around here too
    endfo
    %do what we're here for: increase counter
    T=T+1
endwhile
%when this reaches the end T will be the answer
```

It is good that when you're solving the problems in lua, you have machine powerful enough to not worry about memory footprint and just fire away with the variable size array. But for the current task it is possible to get rough upper limit for memory as : 1+2*( num_v+num_h ).
Once again, in direct simulation you might have less particles, but since every interaction with special tile removes special tile and adds a pair of particles, you will never have more than that.